# How to use SGWTEE_HOME?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am using smart gwt 2.0.3 on windows xp.

I have set a `classpath` variable named SGWTEE_HOME in my Eclipse 3.4, which is pointing to the all folder. (In which all the jar files resides)

Now to add jar files I have done: right click on the my application -> properties ->Java build path then I click on add jar and try to add jar file from memory location.

Now I just want to ask: how can I point to my SGWTEE_HOME to add jar to my application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After puuitng 2hrs I got it, It is by using Add Variables button.